# Call option pricing using CCR model - derivation problem

Tags: option-pricing, binomial

I'm viewing the following derivation of a Call Option price using the CRR model. There is one piece of the derivation which I cannot understand.

\begin{align}
C_0 &= e^{-rT} \sum_{i=0}^{N} (S_{0}\,u^{N-i}\,d^{i} - K)^{+} \binom {N}{i} q^{N-i}(1-q)^{i}\\
&= e^{-rN \Delta t} \sum_{i=a}^{N} (S_{0}\,u^{N-i}\,d^{i} - K) \binom {N}{i} q^{N-i}(1-q)^{i}\\
&= S_0 \sum_{i=a}^{N} \binom {N}{i} (u\,q\,e^{-r \Delta t})^{N-i}\, (d\,e^{-r \Delta t}\,(1- q))^{i} - Ke^{-rT} \sum_{i=a}^{N} \binom {N}{i} q^{N-i} (1-q)^{i}\\
&= S_0 \sum_{i=a}^{N} \binom {N}{i} \overline{q}^{N-i}\, (1 - \overline{q})^{i} - Ke^{-rT} \sum_{i=a}^{N} \binom {N}{i} q^{N-i} (1-q)^{i}\\
&= S_0 \mathcal{Q}_1 - K e^{-rT} \mathcal{Q}_2
\end{align}

where $\overline{q} = uqe^{-r\Delta t}$.

$\textbf{Question}$

If $\overline{q} = uqe^{-r\Delta t}$, then I'm assuming $(1-\overline{q}) = d\,e^{-r \Delta t}\,(1- q)$, however I cannot seem to derive this equality.

Appreciate any help understanding why.

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
q= \frac{e^{r\Delta t} -d}{u-d}.
\end{align*}
Then, 
\begin{align*}
u = \frac{e^{r\Delta t} -d}{q} + d.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
1-\bar{q} &= 1-uqe^{-r\Delta t}\\
&=1- \big(e^{r\Delta t} -d\big)e^{-r\Delta t}-dqe^{-r\Delta t}\\
&=de^{-r\Delta t} -dqe^{-r\Delta t}\\
&=de^{-r\Delta t}(1-q).
\end{align*}

Comment: Of course it is, how embarrassing. In my defence it's been a long day. Many thanks Gordon, appreciated.